# WPF Entity Framework Loading Process Stucks

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, progress-bar

currently i am working with the project in C# WPF with entity framework, i had used MahApps.Metro package for UI, i need to implement the ProgreeBar or LoadingIndicator or anything that idicates that my app is not stuck,

Whenever i made any kind of operation first time, my apps stucks for few second and it seems like its hang,

In web apps i had implemented AJAX call, loading process with

```
.ajaxStart()
.ajaxStop()
```

So my question is does anyone know or is there any way to implement every call of app or entity framework or any process how can i implement ProgressBar or GIF Loader or anything that shows process.

I had tries ProgessBar of MahApps.Metro but whenever I start that ProgressBar it Stucks untill that process complete.

EDITED:

Some of Code is,

```
private void ShowClientWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myProgess.IsIndeterminate = true; //its for progressbar

        myFrame.Source = new Uri("MyViews/ClientView.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        myProgess.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
```

Thanks,

Gaurav Oza

Comment: I dont think the bottleneck is the code above. Loading a new XAML page should take almost no time (until you have 10.000 controls on it). 
What are you doing inside the page Constructor and/or the Loaded event?

Comment: @corradolab: i know that, and i am doing nothing in my constructor and Windows loading event, both are blank.

Comment: @corradolab: in above code, whenever i call this function, it stuck for few seconds and then doing its job. like if i print any message on first line of this function then it will print after few seconds. its working perfectly but whenever i fire any event it stuck for few seconds and then it processing, i dont know why is this happeing.

Comment: Do you have third party controls in your ClientView.xaml?

Comment: Nope, i didn't use any third party control in my View, yeah but I had implemented MahApps.Metro package in my whole app.

Comment: In your View constructor you should at least create the ViewModel... Isn't it? Mabye it's the ViewModel (or the Model) Constructor that is slowing down. Be sure to follow all the object chain you create when you start your View.
And post some code :)

Comment: Nop buddy, I haven't created any instance in my constructor, i am just simply adding ClientView.Xaml in my frame source. that's it, Nothing more. and even codes stucks when the ShowClientWindow method is called. window is stucking in between method call and executing of first line of ShowClientWindow method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to display a ProgressBar to let the user think the application is not stuck, but to use async calls to actually avoid being stuck.

Entity Framework 6 does support [async query and save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx#async)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i tries async. thats not a big issue, suppose i click on button and on click event i load frame itemsource then it stucks for few seconds and then it will respond. this was also happened in async mathos.